# deleteMany in moongose with first condition same but second condition varies

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making a simple api in node js and try to delete multiple document at once.The documents has  two field **'name'** and **'phone'**.The name is same but phone is varies.How to acheive this,suggest me any idea.I have checked my api throug postman and it gives the message

```
{
    "stringValue": "\"[ 9888889999, 888888 ]\"",
    "valueType": "Array",
    "kind": "Number",
    "value": [
        9888889999,
        888888
    ],
    "path": "phone",
    "reason": {
        "generatedMessage": true,
        "code": "ERR_ASSERTION",
        "actual": false,
        "expected": true,
        "operator": "=="
    },
    "name": "CastError",
    "message": "Cast to Number failed for value \"[ 9888889999, 888888 ]\" (type Array) at path \"phone\" for model \"group\""
}
```

My code is

```
router.get('/delete_members',(req,res)=>{
        Group.deleteMany({name:req.body.name,phone:{$in:[req.body.phone]}},(err,doc)=>{
            if(err)
            res.send(err);
            else res.json(doc)
        })
    })
```

The  database document is

```
_id
62e37c2a9f2011c103402b7d
name
"college group"
phone
9888889999
__v
0
_id
62e37c2a9f2011c103402b7e
name
"Family Group"
phone
888888
__v
0
_id
62e37c2a9f2011c103402b7f
name
"Family Group"
phone
9888889999
__v
0
_id
62e37c5f839bb9c7fb2ed4c8
name
"Family Group"
phone
9888889999
__v
0
_id
62e37c5f839bb9c7fb2ed4c9
name
"Family Group"
phone
9888889999
__v
0
_id
62e37c5f839bb9c7fb2ed4ca
name
"Family Group"
phone
9888889999
__v
0
_id
62e37c5f839bb9c7fb2ed4cb
name
"Family Group"
phone
9888889999
__v
0
_id
62e37c5f839bb9c7fb2ed4cc
name
"Family Group"
phone
9888889999
__v
0
```

The schema is

```
const groupSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    phone:Number
})
```

postman request

```
http://localhost:8000/delete_members
{
    "name":"Family Group",
    "phone":[888888,9888889999]
}
```

Comment: please post the API request and schema.

Comment: I have added schema and postman  api request

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have an array inside array, thats why it brakes.

You have this in the mongodb: `[req.body.phone]` and you are sending this `[888888,9888889999]`, which at the end creates `[[888888,9888889999]]`.

The `$in` will try to parse every single item in array, so it takes the first item - the `[888888,9888889999]` and try to parse it as number.

So all you have to do is `{$in:req.body.phone}` and maybe you should rename it to `phones` so it is more clear you are expecting an array of numbers, not single one.